# Waveform pattern detection in time series

Tags: discrete-signals, dft, discrete-wavelet-transform

I have some IMU data which I am using to detect activity patterns - walking, running etc.

In order to differentiate one activity from another I need to do pattern matching in time series. Different walks will have similar accelerometer patterns but will be either longer or shorter.

I initially thought about using simple cross correlation but I realized cross correlation doesn't work well for signals that are not repeated exactly in time domain. This led me to wavelets which I believe can provide basis functions that can be expanded or squeezed in time scale. Am I on the right path or should I look at other techniques like machine learning or conventional methods like STFT

Ex: Triangular sine wave type patterns with varying period.

Comment: Hello Vishnu, it's not quite clear what you're asking here. Please put in more effort to explain what you've researched so far, what your context is, and how wavelets came into consideration.

Comment: I have some IMU data which I am using to detect activity patterns - walking, running etc. In order to differentiate one activity from another I need to do pattern matching in time series. Different walks will have similar accelerometer patterns but will be either longer or shorter. I initially thought about using simple cross correlation but I realized cross correlation doesn't work well for signals that are not repeated exactly in time domain. This led me to wavelets which I believe can provide basis functions that can be expanded or squeezed in time scale.

Comment: Could you add all your comment to your question's text? That would be better!

Comment: Done! Thanks for being patient!

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion. If you have some knowledge of the original waveform, you may choose a mother wavelet that resembles most the given waveform and expand data with the given wavelet. This can also be done with image data. Now your wavelet coefficient will have high amplitude whenever the designated waveform appears in the data. Moment matching can also be used to extract waveforms of similar shape.